# How to make a logfile of the files being transferred to some other server

Tags: bash, logs

I have a scenario where I am receiving multiple files in a directory and I need to transfer those files received in 60 mins to some other server. So for that I use below command.

```
{ find -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin -60| cut -d'/' -f2 | sed 's/^/put /' ; echo bye ; } | \
    /usr/local/bin/sshpass -p password sftp -oBatchMode=no username@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/folder
```

Now, I need to modify the command and make a log file where i need to print the filenames of files being transferred.
I made below script but somehow not convinced with the script as the logfile is also getting transferred and also running *find* command twice can result in some data discrepancy as might be by the time log file is getting generated a new file is received and gets transferred. Please suggest how to fix this.

```
#!/bin/bash

file=/root/test/file_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S)

find -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin -60| cut -d'/' -f2 > $file

{ find -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin -60| cut -d'/' -f2 | sed 's/^/put /' ; echo bye ; } | \
    /usr/local/bin/sshpass -p password sftp -oBatchMode=no username@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/folder
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tee` to store the file names to a file as part of the pipe.

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin -60| cut -d'/' -f2 | tee -a /path/to/log.file | sed 's/^/put /'
```

`-a` will append if the file already exists.

Comment: Thank you @nohillside I used the tee command and works as expected.